# Copy file from Windows to Linux when a shell script is executed

Tags: shell-script, scp, cygwin

I have a program on Linux server, which runs a shell script on Linux server. (say `/tmp/ShellScript.sh`).

Now I want to copy a file placed on my Windows Machine location `C:\WindowsFolder\FileToCopy` to Linux System  directory `/tmp`, **only** whenever `/tmp/ShellScript.sh` is executed on Linux.

How can I achieve this ?

I can also manipulate the script `/tmp/ShellScript.sh` itself and write the logic in that, considering it is empty by default.

Comment: Add the copy line to the script?  You do have passwordless `ssh` enabled?

Comment: You do have passwordless ssh enabled? -- Yes, I can use sshpass as well in case its not. But what I'm not able to understand is that how Linux shell script can run some command in Windows (Just like I need here to copy file from Windows to Linux)

Comment: I know I can have a .bat file with scp command, running which can copy file from Windows to Linux using scp protocol. But the twist here is that i want this operation to be performed when  /tmp/ShellScript.sh is executed

Comment: You can add another line to your `/tmp/ShellScript.sh` on your Linux server to run something like `ssh $WINHOST C:\some\windows\path\script.bat`

Comment: The question is rather vague. Where is that Linux? WSL? VM? Cloud? What is that Windows? Furthermore, besides being vague, dealing purely with Windows is borderline out of topic here.

Comment: Linux and Windows OS are installed on 2 separate machines. Both these machines are connected to same wireless Network

Comment: What's the relevance of the [tag:cygwin] tag here?

Answer (score 2):

Create one executable file with extension .bat in the windows and add the comment given below in file, execute this .bat file whenever you want.

Comment to copy the file from windows to linux,

```
pscp -pw password C:\WindowsFolder\FileToCopy $user@$ip:/tmp
```

Comment: Thanks Ebin, but how do i run this .bat file in windows WHENEVER /tmp/ShellScript.sh IS EXECUTED ON LINUX

Comment: @Rahul *but how do i run this .bat file in windows* You need to put that requirement in your question, too.  That's a lot different from simply copying a file.

Comment: Hi, you can automate this task in windows using Task Scheduler.

Comment: Hello, The issue with Task Scheduler is that, I need to decide some frequency when say every 10 minute , to copy the file.. But when /tmp/ShellScript.sh is ran, it has to do some other operations with the copied file as well. So in case of Task Scheduler if the frequency is every 10 minutes, and the /tmp/ShellScript.sh is called in the 1st minutes it has to wait for 9 minutes to get the file.Which would be an issue.

Comment: The task scheduler works as same as  Linux CRON. If the frequency time is every 10 minutes means, the task scheduler executes the script every 10 minutes. The time taken to complete the task depends on the size of the file.